# Need a deterministic nonstationary function

Tags: stationarity, gaussian-process

Can anyone give me an example of a 1D deterministic function that is nonstationary?  I want to try fitting a stationary Gaussian Process to data generated from a nonstationary function in hopes of better understanding what happens when the stationarity assumption is violated.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I meant a deterministic function. I'll update my question.

Comment: Wouldn't any non-constant function quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random walk, such as $x_t=a+x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$, where $\varepsilon_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$

You can generate a function like $x_t=x_0+at$ if you remove the random component.

Unlike stationary AR(1) process like $x_t=x_{t-1}/2+\varepsilon_t$

Comment: Isn't $x_t=x_0+\sigma t$ just a straight line?

Comment: @ZERO, yes. It's non-stationary (in mean) function. If you need non-stationary in volatility then this will work $x_t=x_0e^{at+\sigma^2/2 t}$.